# Is it possible to override std::env::Args in Rust?

Tags: rust, environment-variables

I am writing a few test cases in my rust application.
I want to set values of set::env::Args, is that allowed in rust ?

"In golang, we can directly assign values to os.Args"

If possible, then what method can I use to do so ?

Comment: The entire thing sounds like an xy problem, what are you *actually* trying to achieve? (also no, whichever you meant, you can't set the return value of `args()`, and you can't update individual items of an `Args` in place).

Comment: You could, in theory, [grab](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/blob/95561b336cf82a8250176eb3c61ea61c90e75d47/library/std/src/sys/unix/args.rs#L105-L109) yourself your own pointer to `argv`, with system dependent unsafe code. But I don't think you can modify `argc`. You're probably much better off making `Args` a (template?) parameter to whatever function you're trying to test.

Answer (score 3):

As you can see in the [documentation](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/env/struct.Args.html), an Args struct is an Iterator that yields Strings. Thus if you make the functions you want to easily pass custom arguments to accept an Iterator<Item=String> parameter, then you can test them easily as well:

```
fn use_args(args: impl Iterator<Item=String>) -> usize {
    args.map(|arg| arg.len()).sum()
}

fn main() {
    println!("{:?}", std::env::args());
    println!("{}", use_args(std::env::args()));
}

#[test]
fn test_use_args() {
    assert_eq!(use_args(std::iter::once("123".to_string())), 3);
    assert_eq!(use_args(std::iter::once("target/debug/playground".to_string())), 6+1+5+1+10);
}
```